# CMake Build From Different Build Tools

Tags: cmake

I am working on a project that uses libraries included as subdirectories, however, one of them doesn't use CMake.

Here's the directory structure:

```
- src
-- tinyxml2
-- ziplib
-- [sources-here]
```

How would I include `ziplib` as it doesn't use CMake as its build tool?

Answer (score 1):

CMake supports execution of arbitrary commands via `add_custom_command`. So whatever buildsystem `ziplib` is using, there will be a way to trigger it via a terminal command.

If you are referring to `ziplib` from https://bitbucket.org/wbenny/ziplib and you happen to build it for Windows, then you can add something similar to the following to you `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build.log
  COMMAND msbuild /m /t:Build /p:Platform=x64 /p:Configuration=Release ZipLib.sln
)
```

There is a good description of `add_custom_command` in [How to Run a Basic `add_custom_command` in CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47333826/how-to-run-a-basic-add-custom-command-in-cmake).

Comment: How would I then link it as a library?

Comment: `target_link_libraries` is the command you are  looking for. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468678/cmake-link-a-library-to-library/14469240#14469240 describes its usage.