# how to add creating protobuf python files

Tags: python-3.x, cmake, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am using python language for my server in gRPC now I need to create the prpto files from cmake as my client in gRPC is written in c++ I have to run this command in CMAkeLISTS.txt file but when I try to run It , no file is created:

```
python3 -m grpc_tools.protoc -I ../protos --python_out=. -- 
pyi_out=. --grpc_python_out=. ../helloworld.proto
```

I want to add this command to CMakeLists.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

# Project
project(myproj)

# Protobuf
set(protobuf_MODULE_COMPATIBLE TRUE)
find_package(Protobuf CONFIG REQUIRED)
message(STATUS "Using protobuf ${protobuf_VERSION}")

# Protobuf-compiler
set(_PROTOBUF_PROTOC $<TARGET_FILE:protobuf::protoc>)

 # gRPC
 find_package(gRPC CONFIG REQUIRED)
 message(STATUS "Using gRPC ${gRPC_VERSION}")
 set(_GRPC_GRPCPP gRPC::grpc++)
 set(_GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN_EXECUTABLE $<TARGET_FILE:gRPC::grpc_cpp_plugin>)
 set(_GRPC_PY_TOOL $<TARGET_FILE:gRPC::grpc_tools::protoc>)

 # Proto file
get_filename_component(hw_proto "helloworld.proto" ABSOLUTE)
get_filename_component(hw_proto_path "${hw_proto}" PATH)

# Generated sources

set(hw_grpc_src_py "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/helloworld_pb2_grpc.py")
set(hw_proto_src_py "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/helloworld_pb2.py")
set(hw_proto_src_pyi "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/helloworld_pb2.pyi")


find_package(PythonInterp REQUIRED)
find_package(Python3 REQUIRED)
add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT "${hw_grpc_src_py}" "${hw_proto_src_py}" "${hw_proto_src_pyi}"
  COMMAND python3 
  ARGS -m  "${_GRPC_PY_TOOL}"
   -I "${hw_proto_path}"
  --python_out "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}"
  --pyi_out "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}"
  --grpc_python_out "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}"
  "${hw_proto}"
  DEPENDS "${hw_proto}")
```

but it does not create the files, did I miss something?
adding

```
add_custom_target(run ALL
DEPENDS "${hw_proto}")
```

also did not work.

Comment: For make COMMAND in `add_custom_command` to be actually executed during the build, the OUTPUT of that command should be **consumed** by some target. For example, it could be a custom target (`add_custom_target`) with appropriate DEPENDS option, or `add_executable` which lists OUTPUT file in its sources. See more in the [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937128/cmake-add-custom-command-not-being-run).

Comment: I also added      add_custom_target(run ALL
    DEPENDS "${dc_proto}") but again no file created.

Comment: I see no variable `dc_proto` in your code, so most likely `${dc_proto}` is empty and your target depends on nothing.

Comment: it was a typo I corrected it. Ithink maybe there is problem in add_custome_command or maybe some packages is needed. But I dont know which and how?

Comment: hw_proto contains file :get_filename_component(hw_proto "helloworld.proto" ABSOLUTE)
get_filename_component(hw_proto_path "${hw_proto}" PATH)

Comment: Why you don't use simple `"${hw_grpc_src_py}"` in your DEPENDS clause? That way you will be sure that the **same file** is listed in the OUTPUT of the custom command and in the DEPENDS of the custom target.

Comment: as you know in protobuffer we have a .proto file and we have to use the command that I wrote to create the python files, so I have to create these files (helloworld_pb2_grpc.py, helloworld_pb2.py,helloworld_pb2.pyi) from helloworld.proto

Comment: Using same DEPENDS in custom command and in custom target doesn't trigger that custom command to be executed. For trigger the command DEPENDS of the custom target should be the same as OUTPUT of the custom command.

Comment: I already have done this and it is working for creating c++ proto files:add_custom_command(
      OUTPUT "${hw_proto_srcs}" "${hw_proto_hdrs}" "${hw_grpc_srcs}" "${hw_grpc_hdrs}" 
      COMMAND ${_PROTOBUF_PROTOC}
      ARGS --grpc_out "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}"
        --cpp_out "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}"
        -I "${hw_proto_path}"
        --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc="${_GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN_EXECUTABLE}"
        "${hw_proto}"
      DEPENDS "${hw_proto}")